# Find specific data from a text file in VBA

Tags: vba

I want to fetch the data from a text file which starts with arrUserActivity in VBA. I'm able to fetch if there is no break line i.e Sample 1 but not for Sample 2.

Sample 1 :
var arrUserActivity = [['9/13/2022 8:49:00 AM','MOA_S10EST','Firoj  Aga','Remote Desktop using VNC 2.0 ','CBM'],['9/13/2022 1:54:00 PM','MOA_S10EST','Aux Tech2','Remote Desktop using VNC 2.0','Routine']];

Sample 2 :
var arrUserActivity = [

['9/13/2022 8:49:00 AM','MOA_S10EST','Firoj  Aga','Remote Desktop using VNC 2.0 ','CBM'],
['9/13/2022 1:54:00 PM','MOA_S10EST','Aux Tech2','Remote Desktop using VNC 2.0 ','Routine']];

My code is  :

```
 WhatToFind = "var arrUserActivity"
    FromFile1 = Path + "\02-Text_Files\" + Site_Name + ".txt"
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open FromFile1 For Input As #FileNum
    Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
    lngCount = lngCount + 1    'increment a counter'
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine    ' read in data 1 line at a time'
    If InStr(1, DataLine, WhatToFind) > 0 Then    'the string is found'
    bFound = True    'set a boolean value to true'
    Exit Do    'and stop the loop'
    End If
    Loop
```

I'm able to fetch data if there is no line break.

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
WhatToFindStart = "var arrUserActivity"
 WhatToFindEnd = "];"
    FromFile1 = Path + "\02-Text_Files\" + Site_Name + ".txt"
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open FromFile1 For Input As #FileNum
    Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
        lngCount = lngCount + 1    'increment a counter'
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine    ' read in data 1 line at a time'
        If InStr(1, DataLine, WhatToFindStart) > 0 Then    'the string is found'
            bFoundStart = True    'set a boolean value to true'
        End If
        If bFoundStart Then
            Data = Data & DataLine
            Data2 = Data2 & Trim(Replace(DataLine, " ", ""))
            If Right(Data2, 2) = WhatToFindEnd Then
                bFound = True
                Debug.Print (Data) 'Here yo have the data in one line
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    Close
```